# Python - How to change final comma to a peroid after a list sentence and insert "and" as well to make a full sentence?

Tags: python

How can I edit this code to make it output something like
"The prime number(s) in your range are: 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, and 29."
if the boundaries are 10 and 30?

```
lower = int(input("Input lower bound"))
upper = int(input("Input upper bound"))
print("The prime number(s) in your range are:", end = " ")
for num in range(lower, upper+1):
  if(num>1):
    for i in range(2,num):
      if(num%i)==0:
        break
    else:
      print(num, end = ", ")
```

Answer (score 3):

Store them in a list and print them at the end , use sep argument to mention separation and end to mention the end.

```
lower = int(input("Input lower bound"))
upper = int(input("Input upper bound"))
print("The prime number(s) in your range are:", end = " ")
primenums = []
for num in range(lower, upper+1):
  if(num>1):
    for i in range(2,num):
      if(num%i)==0:
        break
    else:
      primenums.append(num)
if len(primenums) > 2:
  print(*primenums[:-1] ,sep = ", ",end=" and ")
  print(prime[-1])
else:
  # if len(primenums) is 1 sep will be ignonred
  print(*primenums,sep=" and ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Store your prime numbers in a list.

```
primes = []
for num in range(lower, upper+1):
  if(num>1):
    for i in range(2,num):
      if(num%i)==0:
        break
    else:
      primes.append(num)
```

Then, format it into a string before printing:

```
if len(primes) <= 2:
    msg = " and ".join(str(p) for p in primes)
else:
    msg = f"{', '.join(str(p) for p in primes[:-1])}, and {primes[-1]}"

print(f"The prime number(s) in your range are: {msg}")
```

`", ".join(...)` joins all elements in the iterator that is passed to it with the string `", "`. The iterator is `str(p) for p in primes[:-1]`. This iterator converts all elements of `primes` except the last one to a string to be joined with `", "`. The `f"..."` construct is called an *f-string* and is my preferred way of string interpolation in python.

Comment: @CrazyChucky It would say `"The prime numbers are 11, and 13"`. In a list of two, the comma looks weird IMO.

Comment: @CrazyChucky Thanks to your comment I realized the `len() == 1` and `== 2` cases could be condensed into a single `if` because `join()` wouldn't add the separator if there's only one element :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```py
lower = int(input("Input lower bound: "))
upper = int(input("Input upper bound: "))

prime_numbers = list()
for num in range(lower, upper + 1):
    if num > 1:
        for i in range(2, num):
            if num % i == 0:
                break
        else:
            prime_numbers.append(str(num))

prepend = "The prime number(s) in your range are:"
if len(prime_numbers) > 2:
    print(f"{prepend} {', '.join(prime_numbers[:-1])} and {prime_numbers[-1]}.")
else:
    print(f"{prepend} {' and '.join(prime_numbers)}.")
```

This would output:

```
Input lower bound: 3
Input upper bound: 10
The prime number(s) in your range are: 3, 5 and 7.

Input lower bound: 7
Input upper bound: 11
The prime number(s) in your range are: 7 and 11.

Input lower bound: 8
Input upper bound: 11
The prime number(s) in your range are: 11.
```

And you could add the special case of no numbers in range (if needed) with something like:

```py
elif prime_numbers:
    print(f"{prepend} {' and '.join(prime_numbers)}.")
else:
    print(f"No prime numbers found in range.")
```